# vaadin7 grid editorField can't set null representation?

Tags: grid, vaadin

still don't have a solution! (┬＿┬)

I try to set the NullRepresentation with empty string with following code, but failed, anyone can help? or other good solution is appreciated.

```
final Collection fields = this.grid.getEditorFieldGroup().getFields();
    fields.stream().forEach((field -> {
        if (field instanceof TextField) {
            ((TextField) field).setNullRepresentation("");
        }
    }));
```

I try to use a custom FieldGroup to override it, but failed again.

```
public class CmsFieldGroup extends FieldGroup {

@Override
public Field<?> getField(final Object propertyId) {
    Field field = null;
    field = super.getField(propertyId);
    if (field instanceof TextField) {
        ((TextField) field).setNullRepresentation("");
    }

    return field;
}

@Override
public Collection<Field<?>> getFields() {
    final Collection<Field<?>> fields = super.getFields();
    fields.stream().forEach((field -> {
        if (field instanceof TextField) {
            ((TextField) field).setNullRepresentation("");
        }
    }));

    return fields;
}
```

}

```
final CmsFieldGroup cmsFieldGroup = new CmsFieldGroup();
    this.grid.setEditorFieldGroup(cmsFieldGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems it can be done as follow, but the code seems ugly.

```
public class CmsFieldGroup extends FieldGroup {

@Override
public Field<?> getField(final Object propertyId) {
    Field field = null;
    field = super.getField(propertyId);
    if (field instanceof TextField) {
        ((TextField) field).setNullRepresentation("");
    }

    return field;
}

@Override
public Collection<Field<?>> getFields() {
    final Collection<Field<?>> fields = super.getFields();
    for (final Field field : fields) {

        try {
            if (field instanceof TextField && !"".equals(((TextField) field).getNullRepresentation())) {
                ((TextField) field).setNullRepresentation("");
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            System.out.print("something wrong");
        }
    }

    return fields;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The following also appears to work:

```
FieldGroup fieldGroup = grid.getEditorFieldGroup();
fieldGroup.setFieldFactory(new MyFieldGroupFieldFactory());
```

with MyFieldGroupFieldFactory defined as follows:

```
class MyFieldGroupFieldFactory extends DefaultFieldGroupFieldFactory {

    @Override
    public <T extends Field> T createField(Class<?> type, Class<T> fieldType) {
        T field = super.createField(type, fieldType);
        if (field instanceof TextField) {
            TextField textField = (TextField) field;
            textField.setNullRepresentation("");
        }
        return field;
    }
}
```